# Use laravel as proxy of frontend

Tags: reactjs, laravel, proxy

I have a laraval project with react application in the same project, before running the react app I have many middleware that check some authorization like if a country is authorized to access or not:

```
 Route::middleware(['firewall.country', 'firewall.ip'])->group(function () {
     Route::get('/{any}', function () {
           return view('app');
      })->where('any', '^(?!api).*$');
});
```

Now I need to deploy the react front separately from laravel project.
My question is how to keep this middleware running before react application.

Comment: Now it depends on your web server. I am very ignorant about filtering IPs (per region), but, for example, using AWS, you can allow or deny countries, so I would ask this question in [sf]. Maybe you can use Cloudflare

Comment: If you are using apache as a webserver and are self hosting then [maxmind geoip](https://maxmind.github.io/mod_maxminddb/) is an option. I think the country level DB is free to use as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use laravel as proxy you can do like this:

```
Route::get('/check', function ($endpoint) {
  $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
  $response = $client->get("https://external-front.com/");
  return response($response->getBody(), $response->getStatusCode())
    ->header('Content-Type', $response->getHeader('Content-Type'));
});
```

But this is a bad idea.
The better way is to change your laravel endpoint like this:

```
 Route::get('/check', function () {
       return 'check';
  })->middleware(['firewall.country', 'firewall.ip']);// here all your middleware before react loaded
```

Then in your react app:

```
 const App = () => {
      useLayoutEffect(() => {
           axios.get('/check')
                .catch(function (error) {
                     if (error.response.status == 403) {
                          //redirect to your access denied page 
                      } 
           });
      }, []);
 }
```